# Tag badges don't show as "Next badge"

Tags: bug, badges, badge-progress

While looking at my profile I noticed I was only 3 votes away from a tag badge but that my "Next badge" was something I was less than half way to achieving:

[image: profile]

Is this a bug or are tag badges not considered?

Comment: That little gear next to it lets you select what badge you want to track, but I don't believe tag badges are an option

Comment: Tag badges go in the far left box, under your reputation. On meta, you can track these at any time. On main, you can only start tracking these after you've hit 20k rep. Basically, they replace your "Next Privilege" tracker.

Comment: What I mentioned in my previous comment is covered [in the blog announcing the profiles](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-ones-big/?cb=1) and there is a [feature-request on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254052/cant-track-tag-badges-without-20k-rep) to try to get this changed.